# Python multiple modules in the same root folder import error

Tags: python, python-module

I'm trying to organise my python project with the following structure:

```html
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><span>RootFolder</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>module1(folder)</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>submodule1(folder)</span>
            <ul>
              <li><span>pyfile1.py</span>
                <ul>
                  <li>function test1()</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
              <li><span>main.py</span>
              </li>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>module2(folder)</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>submodule2(folder)</span>
            <ul>
              <li><span>pyfile2.py</span>
                <ul>
                  <li>function test2()</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
              <li><span>main.py</span>
              </li>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Two separate modules into the same rootFoder.
This is the content of module1.main file:

```
import module1.submodule1 as sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sm.pyfile1.test1()
```

But when I'm running `python -m module1.main` I have the following error

> module 'module1.submodule1' has no attribute 'pyfile1'

My goal is to have multiple modules with their own main entry points under the same rootFolder.
What is wrong? I don't understand why this is not correct.

Comment: You are trying to access the pyfile1 module directly from your module1 main file. Instead, you should import it first before you can use it. 

For example:

```import module1.submodule1.pyfile1 as pyf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyf.test1()```

Comment: thank you for answer, why I cannot import submodule1 entirely?

Comment: Python will be looking for the submodule1 module within the same folder as the main module, not in the root folder. You will need to explicitly specify the path to the submodule1 module

Comment: but that I don't understand, the submodule1 IS within the same folder as the main